# Vue.js render error with Firestore and vuefire

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, rendering, hook, vuefire

I have a problem in my Vue.js application

Indeed, my component is working properly, however I have errors in the console because it seems to me that the component is rendered several times during its life cycle, and the first time, when it is rendered, it does not find not my races variable at the time of the display because the method db.collection ('courses') has not yet run. How to do?

thank you

My code on JsFiddle:

```
firestore() { }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gf9qhsjr/1/

**The Error :**

> vue.esm.js?efeb:591 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'title' of undefined"